# after downloading files from url using c#.net and open that files in our local machine its is showing file corrupted

Tags: c#

```
    private void btndownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         string a 
        ="https://dev.azure.com/vinurajv4179/_apis/wit/attachments/e5ad18bf- 
         8ab6-4355-abe5-87e4ad7ebe05"
         Uri uri1 = new Uri(a);
         WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
         webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
         webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri1, @"D:\\" + 
         "attach1.png");
      }
```

After downloading files from the Azure devops into my local machine using c# code and atter opening that file ,the file is showing corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain points:

1. Make sure that the file you are trying to download from the URL exists when we access the URL.
2. Make sure that file is an image file with jpeg extension.
3. `webClient.DownloadFileAsync` downloads file in background. Either put await before it or simpy use `webClient.DownloadFile`.
4. The file you are trying to download requires authentication & authorization. Make sure you are passing appropriate header values or whatever required to make your request authenticated.

Comment: While i am passing url directly in my browser ,i can view my files and the same url im directly hard coding in my code and downloaded ,after downloaded when i am opening that downloaded file it is not opening

Comment: @Vinu you should open the URL in incognito mode (Chrome's name). It redirects to a login page. See point 4 of Ankush's answer.